# URL session saving image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

quick question. I want to extract the dowloaded image from the url and save it to a UI Image.

How would I do this?

```
fileprivate func beginDownload() {

        let url = URL(string: "URL")!

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: operationQueue)

        let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)

        downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Here are my URL session protocol stubs:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        print(totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite)

    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

        print("Finished dowloading file")
    }
```

Comment: Load the image from the url `location` when `didFinishDownloadingTo` is called - for [example](https://medium.com/swlh/tracking-download-progress-with-urlsessiondownloaddelegate-5174147009f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the image from the download `location` created in the delegate method `urlSession(_:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingTo:)`:

```swift
class Request: NSObject {

    func getPicture() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://media.tractorsupply.com/is/image/TractorSupplyCompany/1305371?$456$")!
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, 
                                 delegate: self, 
                                 delegateQueue: nil)
        session.downloadTask(with: url).resume()
    }

}

extension Request: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, 
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: location), 
              let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
        print(image)
    }

}

Request().getPicture()
```